# Мердже без checkout

Tags: git

Можно ли оставаясь в текущей ветке, обновить изменения в другой ветке к примеру dev и смерджить изменения из ветки dev в текущую ветку?

1. Создал ветку от ветки dev, назвал его ficha
2. Переключился на ветку ficha
3. через неделю захотел смерджиться с изменениями на ветке dev
   для мерджа я перерключаюсь на ветку dev, git pull, опять перключась обратно на ficha, и только мерджусь, 
   Хотел чтобы можно было без переключения на ветку dev, скачать изменения и смерджить с веткой ficha

Comment: ну почти. `git fetch && git merge origin/dev`. Вот только ветка dev не будет мержена.

Comment: @KoVadim, я, вот, не понял ни автора до конца, ни вас. Обновить *индекс* ветки (если она мониторится) можно не переключаясь (`git fetch <local branch> <remote> <remote branch>`).

Comment: обновить индекс ветки? в гите как бы один индекс на один рабочий каталог. Просто так обновить локально ветку не выйдет, так как может понадобиться мерж, а его сложновато сделать без рабочего каталога (кроме fast forward). Поєтому я и предлагаю собственно сделать fetch для всех веток и потом мерж с ссылкой на удаленную ветку.